# Преобразование SQL запросов в JAVA Class

Tags: java, sql, orm, preparedstatement

Стоит задача преобразовать некоторые sql запросы в конкретные Java файлы. 
Допустим у меня есть запрос на создание таблицы:

```
CREATE TABLE `persons` (
  `Id` int AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Name` varchar(25),
  PRIMARY KEY (`Id`)
);

CREATE TABLE `autos` (
  `Id` int AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Person` int,
  `Title` varchar(100),
  PRIMARY KEY (`Id`),
  CONSTRAINT `autoToPerson` FOREIGN KEY (`PersonId`) REFERENCES `persons`(`Id`) ON DELETE CASCADE
```

);

Эти две таблицы надо преобразовать в класс Java. 
Я нашел статью об этом на хабре: https://habrahabr.ru/post/330938/
Но там наоборот, классы преобразовывают в запросы.

Слышал про такие понятия как `Statement, PreparedStatement, ResultSet`.  Но не понимаю о чем это.

Жду от вас ответов, советов, направлений.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16524481/4854931

Comment: Почитайте про Hibernate. Некоторые IDE, например NetBeans IDE умеют генерить классы по таблицам.

Answer (score 2):

Если нет понимания что такое Statement, PreparedStatement, ResultSet и CallableStatement еще,  я бы посоветовал сначала разобраться, что это такое и как это работает, посмотреть что такое JDBC и только потом смотреть в сторону ORM.

Формулировка "преобразовать некоторые sql запросы в конкретные Java файлы" вообще вызывает много вопросов. Что под этим понимается? Выполнить запрос из Java класса?
Если да, вот простейший пример:
http://www.javamadesoeasy.com/2015/07/jdbc-statement-example-execute-create.html

Answer (score 1):

Айдар,

Есть такая концепция - называется [ORM - Object Relational Mapping](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/ORM)- отображение Java объектов на БД.

В данном случае речь идет о том, чтобы отобразить ваши таблицы на Java классы. Есть множество различных способов как это можно сделать. Наиболее популярная (как правильно написали в комментариях) - [ORM Hibernate](http://hibernate.org/orm/) - начните с него.

> Слышал про такие понятия как Statement, PreparedStatement, ResultSet. Но не понимаю о чем это

Это более низкоуровневая история - это о том, как из Java достучаться до SQL, вкратце это описывается пакетом [java.sql](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/package-summary.html) он же [JDBC](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Database_Connectivity) - тот же Hibernate в своих кишках реализует ORM с помощью JDBC.